# Query error MySQL php

Tags: php, mysql

Im new to php and my sql in trying to get all the results from this table if nothing is selected but for some reason its always displaying one result. Any ide why

```
$query = "SELECT *, ROUND(AVG(d.rating),0) FROM restaurant AS r, review AS d WHERE 1=1 ";
if($vicinity) $query .= "AND r.vicinity=\"$vicinity\" ";
if($cuisine)  $query .= "AND r.cuisine=\"$cuisine\" ";
if($price)    $query .= "AND r.price=\"$price\"";
if($name)    $query .= "AND r.name LIKE \"%$name%\"";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

and im only getting the first item on the table

Comment: Please look into prepared statements

Comment: You need to show how you display the result. This might be because you are not looping through the `$result` array properly.

Comment: 1. Use prepared statements like Prowla said, and 2. string literals in SQL are surrounded by single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: echo $query before the mysql_query() and see the what in the $query it will helps you]

Comment: what is the result you get after echo $query;

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { -- only getting the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and get results and use iterator to parse and print in a loop will get. See also [this tutorial](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into PDO personally. You can find out a lot about it in the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 0):

guessing you're only getting one result because the avg call without a group by is triggering some interesting behavior. try adding a group by, and i'm guessing you also want to associate the restaurants and reviews with a join. eg:

```
$query = "SELECT *, ROUND(AVG(d.rating),0) FROM restaurant AS r LEFT JOIN review AS d on r.id = d.restaurant_id WHERE 1=1";
...
...
$query .= ' GROUP BY r.id';
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

per the thread, sounds like you should look into prepared statements as well :). and the `SELECT *` should probably also just be `SELECT r.*` - the data returned as part of the * results from the rating won't be meaningful after the group by (the r.* and round(avg(d.rating),0) values should be though)